# How to update embedded JSON file in iOS app bundle whenever refresh button is clicked

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, web-services, cocoa-touch

I have a application where my data is offline in `JSON` format but i want the app to update the `JSON` file from the internet whenever refresh button is touched.

I have used `JSON` file as local database and the updated database would be generated on the server when the database is updated. The app should download the `JSON` file from internet and use it as the local database.

How this can be made possible? I am confused with what method is to be used and how it can be done.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot overwrite a `JSON` that is bundled with your app. However, you can update a `JSON` stored outside of your app bundle - for example in your app's `Documents` folder.

You will need methods for saving a `JSON`:

```
-(void)saveJSONWithData:(NSData *)data
{
     NSString *path = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] stringByAppendingFormat:@"/data.json"];

     [data writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
}


- (NSURL *)applicationDocumentsDirectory 
{
    return [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory 
                                                   inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
}
```

You will also need to download the `JSON`. Bet way to do it is to perform a request in the background so the `UI` thread is not blocked.

```
- (void)getJSONDataAtURL:(NSURL *)urlWithJSON
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0),^
    {
        // Download the data in background.
        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:urlWithJSON];

       [self saveJSONWithData:data];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^
        {
            // Do your tasks on the main thread.
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: so i will have to set my default data that is json file in the documents folder and then update it

Comment: Yes, you are right. Additionally what you can do is when your app starts for the first time just copy the `JSON` data from app bundle to `Documents` and always reference this location instead of bothering if you read the original JSON from the bundle or the `Documents`.